# Google tag manager won't push event's to datalayer on Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement Tag Manager in my Android Application following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/), but for some reason I can't push event's to the datalayer.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);

    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferFresh(GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_default_container_v2);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDataLayer().push("event", "screenName");
            // Using the "pushEvent" method doesn't work either
            // TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDataLayer().pushEvent("screenName", DataLayer.mapOf());
        }
    }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

When I try to run my app, all my log is saying is this

```
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Attempting to load a container from the resource ID 2131099649 (com.example.cpe.gatestapp:raw/gtm_default_container_v2)
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Deleted 0 expired items
W/GoogleTagManager﹕ Failed to extract the container from the resource file. Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ The container was successfully loaded from the resource (using binary file)
E/GoogleTagManager﹕ Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Attempting to load resource from disk
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-XXXXXX delay=0
D/GoogleTagManager﹕ Setting previous container version: MQ$0
E/GoogleTagManager﹕ Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ The Disk resource was successfully read.
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Start loading resource from network ...
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Successfully loaded supplemented resource: zzi_p: "MQ$0"
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ No change for container: GTM-XXXXXX
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-XXXXXX delay=43200000
D/GoogleTagManager﹕ Setting previous container version: MQ$0
E/GoogleTagManager﹕ Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ setting refresh time to current time: 1435818825632
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Load resource from network finished.
```

Screenshots from my GA and Tag Manager accounts:

[image: tigger's]

[image: TagManager screen]

[image: Google analytics dump]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is pretty simple after I figured it out.

So I have created an Analytics Tracker which track's if my application crashes. I have made a option, that if i'm running my application in debug mode aka running it from AndroidStudio, my Tracker will make a 'dryRun'.

So I figured that the TagManager is using the Analytics tracker to send all the events. Which is why it helped to disable the dryRun on my GoogleAnalytics tracker.